# How to prove generalized distribution law in ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the ring $(R,\oplus,\odot)$ , and the generalized addition obtained  $\displaystyle \bigoplus_{k=0}^ma_k$by the recursive definition , how to prove  $\boxed{\bigoplus_{k=0}^ma_k\odot\bigoplus_{j=0}^{n}b_j=\bigoplus_{k=0}^m\bigoplus_{j=0}^n(a_k\odot b_j)}$？
I used mathematical induction and proved that it is true when $n=0$, but I encountered a problem when pushing $n=r+1$ from $n=r$. What should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfOsL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are having a problem with induction (you really should tell us what "problem" you encountered, rather than just say you had a problem). For a fixed $m$, assuming the result holds for $n=r$, that is, that
$$\bigoplus_{k=0}^na_k \odot \bigoplus_{j=0}^rb_j = \bigoplus_{k=0}^n\bigoplus_{j=0}^r(a_k\odot b_j),$$
we have
$$\begin{align*}
\bigoplus_{k=0}^n a_k \odot \bigoplus_{j=0}^{r+1}b_j &= \bigoplus_{k=0}^n a_k\odot \left(\bigoplus_{j=0}^rb_j \oplus b_{r+1}\right)\\
&=\left( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n a_k\odot \bigoplus_{j=0}^r b_j\right) \oplus \left(\bigoplus_{k=0}^n a_k \odot b_{r+1}\right) \tag{1}\\
&= \left(\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\bigoplus_{j=0}^r a_kb_j\right) \oplus \bigoplus_{k=0}^n a_kb_{r+1}\\
&= \bigoplus_{k=0}^n \bigoplus_{j=0}^{r+1} a_kb_j. \tag{2}
\end{align*}$$
Here, $(1)$ follows by regular distributivity, and $(2)$ by general commutativity of $\oplus$.

Comment: thanks a lot!  I forgot that  $\forall n\in\N,\bigodot_{k=0}^na_k\odot\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}b_k=\bigodot_{k=0}^{n}(a_k\odot b_k)$ is satisfied in the abel group